# Como importar um CSV enorme em Python?

Tags: python

Olá,

Estou trabalhando com um arquivo de matrículas do Censo Escolar. Quero importar no Python mas nenhuma das respostas que estou olhando está funcionando. O pandas pd.read_csv() demora muito tempo e não consegue abrir.

Eu queria a forma mais simples e fácil de simplesmente abrir um arquivo gigante sem acabar com a capacidade de processamento da minha máquina e que eu possa trabalhar depois.

Comment: Veja se você consegue resultados melhores utilizando o [pacote datatable](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), ou seu [equivalente em R](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), ambos focados em trabalhar com datasets grandes (maiores que a RAM disponível no seu computador).